# Comparison between these Ito Lemma versions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

According to wikipedia :
[image]

I found another version :

[image]

Please explain the difference for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case it is not necessarily the case that $dX_t=\mu_t\,dt+\sigma_t\,dB_t$.
But the second case  should imply the first. What is $dX_t\cdot dX_t$ for the first case ?

Comment: for the first cast , when $dX_t*dX_t$ it gives ${\sigma_t}^2dt$

Comment: Yes: that's it.